# How to automatically add '&' after each command in a terminal

Tags: 12.04, command-line, guake

I use [guake](http://guake.org/) as a sort of "run" command, because my lxde launcher often misbehaves. So I just enter the command line in guake followed by & (So I get back the control of the console). Is there a way to configure the terminal to automatically append & to all the commands I enter, or any other way to make it behave like I am adding & sign to my commands

Comment: Or you could use an application launcher, like [gmrun](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gmrun/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind adding `&` and new line after pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key:

```
bind 'RETURN: "&\n"'
```

Answer (score 1):

Needing to do the same thing, I started creating BASH aliases a couple of years ago, and my `.bash_aliases` file now counts 164 lines. The same file is also synchronized among my workstations, for convenience.

An example of a line in which a `&` in the end is useful is:

```
alias winserver='rdesktop winserver &'
```

I hope this works for you.