# Remove a 'bind' entry from terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, shortcut-keys

I'm an infrequent Ubuntu user and saw the accepted solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310197/how-to-automatically-add-after-each-command-in-a-terminal/310352#310352?newreg=7a721596ecda479695e6cefbfc518093) to a query of mine. I'm wondering how to restore default keybind (only newline, no '&' at the end). Where exactly are these bindings stored?

Thanks, and apologies if the question has been asked before. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same terminal type the following command to remove the `bind` entry:

```
bind 'RETURN: "\n"'; foo
```

and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

It will complain about the foo command not found:

```
No command 'foo' found, did you mean[...]
```

But it will let the first part of the command to run properly thus restoring the behaviour of the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: That works, thanks! Wasn't working without 'foo', wonder why.

Comment: @MoaazAhmad `foo` is just a placeholder that will receive the last `&` character allowing the first part of the command (including the `;`) to run normally.